# Bad URI when trying to connect to Openstack

Tags: ruby, uri, openstack

I'm trying to connect to an Openstack (devstack) using the 'ruby-openstack' gem with the line:

```
os = OpenStack::Connection.create({
    :username => "admin", 
    :auth_method => 'password',
    :api_key => "supersecret",
    :auth_url => "http://192.168.52.162/" })
```

But I got this error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): 
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in 'split'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:211:in 'parse'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:747:in 'parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/openstack-1.1.2/lib/openstack/connection.rb:399:in 'initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/openstack-1.1.2/lib/openstack/connection.rb:263:in 'new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/openstack-1.1.2/lib/openstack/connection.rb:263:in 'init'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/openstack-1.1.2/lib/openstack/compute/connection.rb:12:in 'initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/openstack-1.1.2/lib/openstack/connection.rb:66:in 'new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/openstack-1.1.2/lib/openstack/connection.rb:66:in 'create'
    from (irb):58
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
```

I don't really understand why my URL "http://192.168.52.162/" is parsed as a bad URI. After analysing the network with Wireshark, the HTTP request seems to be sent as I see the GET request and the HTTP 200 OK response.

Why is the URI considered wrong and how can the HTTP request be sent if there is an error in the line?

Comment: If you get a 200 back, what is the body of the response?

Comment: It's the html for the openstack dashboard !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not necessarily complaining about your URL, but instead about some sort of response URL:

https://github.com/ruby-openstack/ruby-openstack/blob/v1.1.2/lib/openstack/connection.rb#L399

```
uri = URI.parse(response["x-server-management-url"])
```

You could try getting into that gem's code on your local machine and adding some logging/debugging to the response object to get a better handle on the error. (`gem which openstack` should get you the path)

Comment: Thanks for the idea ! It looks like the response has no attribute "x-server-management-url" but only `date
server
vary
x-frame-options
content-language
set-cookie
content-length
content-type`

Comment: Sure thing. That would mean `x-server-management-url` is coming back `nil`, which would explain the error (note, line numbers are a little off, but I imagine it's close): https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_1_rc1/lib/uri/common.rb#L101-L157
All I can suggest is that you'll have to figure out why you're not getting that uri back in the response. Or, if you think that's a bug, maybe file an issue on the openstack gem repo? Could it be an incompatibility between Ruby 1.9.1 and that gem/gem version?